# Separate centroids from examples into two lists while reading a file

Tags: python

I'm having trouble to read a file and separate its information intow two different lists. The file looks like this:

```
#Sample number, nick name and features:
#Id; name; heads; eyes; mouths; legs; tails; horns; rings; thorns; scales
#List of exemplars:
ff44578jhT; strangeBug; 2; 7; 3; 5; 2; 1; 71; 235; 312
sahfhfdjbd; afgefd; 2; 8; 6; 5; 8; 9; 9; 6; 45
adhfcbidsgh; diufhek; 4; 5; 6; 8; 5; 6; 2; 3; 45
#List of samples:
k345fv78; littleMonster; 2; 4; 3; 0; 2; 1; 89; 2345; 0
dufihsd; diufhek; 4; 5; 6; 8; 5; 6; 2; 3; 45
```

I can read it and ignoring the line that starts with # but only appending lines into one single list. Here's the code:

```
def readFileExamples(filename):
    in_file=open(filename)
    for i in range(3):
        in_file.readline()
    examples=[]
    for line in in_file:
        if '#' not in line:
            ident, name, heads, eyes, mouths, legs, tails, horns, rings, thorns, scales = line.strip().split('; ')        
            examples.append((ident, name, heads, eyes, mouths, legs, tails, horns, rings, thorns, scales))
    in_file.close()
    return examples
```

My goal is to have a list with all the examplars and another list with all the samples. The examplars and samples aren't a fixed number of lines, it can have more so I can't read the file acording to their position in the file.

Comment: cant you add one more `if`  stmt to check `#List of samples:` and after that check, simply add line to new list `samples`

Comment: Normally a CSV file does contain only one set of data.

Comment: @SagarRohankar wouldn't that just skip the line?

Comment: @What this specific file has more than one set of data

Comment: @Inês, yes if you `continue` the loop, it will get skipped, then its matter of adding next line to new list.

Comment: @SagarRobankar I'm not really sure what you're trying to say

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here you go, I have removed the first 3 line skip code, as its anyway going to get covered in # skip

```
        def readFileExamples(filename):
            in_file=open(filename)

            examples = []
            tmp = []
            for line in in_file:
                if line == "#List of samples:\n":
                    # examples are over, we will start samples now
                    examples = tmp.copy()
                    tmp.clear()
                if '#' not in line:
                    ident, name, heads, eyes, mouths, legs, tails, horns, rings, thorns, scales = line.strip().split('; ')
                    tmp.append((ident, name, heads, eyes, mouths, legs, tails, horns, rings, thorns, scales))
            in_file.close()

            samples = tmp.copy()
            return examples, samples

        if __name__ == '__main__':
            print(readFileExamples('scratch.txt'))
```